# How do I install mssql jdbc driver to confluent / kafka

Tags: java, jdbc, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I'm trying to create a connector through the rest and it won't work stating that `"Failed to find any class that implements Connector and which name matches com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver`

I'm on ubuntu 16.04 and I've tried the following and each time i try something new i stop then start confluent with `confluent stop` `confluenct start`

download mssql-jdbc-6.2.2.jre8.jar

`export CLASSPATH=/path/to/dir/*`

`cp path/to/mssql-jdbc-6.2.2.jre8.jar /usr/share/rest-utils`
`cp path/to/mssql-jdbc-6.2.2.jre8.jar /usr/share/java/kafka`
`cp path/to/mssql-jdbc-6.2.2.jre8.jar /usr/share/java/kafka-connect-jdbc`
`cp path/to/mssql-jdbc-6.2.2.jre8.jar /usr/share/java/res-utils`
`cp path/to/mssql-jdbc-6.2.2.jre8.jar /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext`

The documentation makes it seem like all i do is add /path/to/jar to to classpath and start confluent. What am i missing.

Further this is my json for creating the connector.

```
{
  "name": "jdbc-source",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "connection.url": "jdbc:sqlserver://sql:1443;User=someone;Password=password;Database=some-deb",
    "mode": "incrementing",
    "incrementing.column.name": "id",
    "topic.prefix": "email",
    "topic.whitelist": "EventLog",
    "name": "jdbc-source"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well it turns out that the connector.class should remain `io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector` so I think these steps are sufficient.

1. add your `mssql-jdbc-6.2.2.jre8.jar` to the CLASSPATH
2. `confluent start`
3. POST the config in the question and replace the connector.class with `io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector`: i also had to remove the port